# Want to convert .pdf into .swf(as3) file

Tags: pdf, swf, adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

How can I convert a .pdf file into .swf(as3) file ?
Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Illustrator can also do this.  Open a PDF and then File -> Export as a SWF.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWFTOOLS](http://www.swftools.org/). It comes with all sorts of free tools for working with flash files, including **PDF2SWF**.

> **PDF2SWF**
>
> A PDF to SWF Converter. Generates one
>   frame per page. Enables you to have
>   fully formatted text, including
>   tables, formulas, graphics etc. inside
>   your Flash Movie. It's based on the
>   xpdf PDF parser from Derek B.
>   Noonburg.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape (inkscape.org(free) can generally take in any pdf and save it as a format you can use in flash.  I don't know if the .eps works with flash, but it's the best one for converting to Illustrator.  The only think to worry about usually is if you have particular fonts in the pdf that aren't installed on your machine.  You can usually find out which ones they are in Adobe reader's properties menu for that document.

Comment: Not that useful if you want each page of the PDF to be its own screen in the Flash.